# Magento 2 : Wrong Download Items and Download Link in Invoice Email

Tags: orders, email, invoice, magento-2.2.1, downloadable

I am developing a website which only selling downloadable products. Guest checkout is enabled with this when customer place an order they receive correct information in email. But when they receive invoice email there are incorrect downloadable item name and download link in invoice email.

I have researched a lot but not understanding what is the issue? is it issue with Magento or something else?

Comment: found any solution?

Comment: @Yogita no still not found solution.

Comment: I had the same issue. The problem was my 3rd party checkout extension. I had to disable it.